# Nuke studio GPU

Tags: video, visual-effects, nuke

I'm working on my first project on nuke studio 10.
The sequence is 10 mins long.
I set the default blink device to my NVidia titan x. My machine is a Mac pro 5,1 
12 cores.

I tried to export the sequence quicktime prores 4444 and I set it to use 6 cores as the threats number.
I wanna know if it's possible to render or export using my gpu becayse it gave me estimated time like 1 hour and a half.

And when I try to export the same sequence from premier pro cc, it takes 4 mins because media encoder is using cuda processing to encode the sequence.

Thanks